# Django : Detecting finishing of a script in the background and other functionalities should work in the meantime

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to execute a command on a simple button press event in my Django project (for which I'm using "subprocess.Popen()" in my views.py ).
After I execute this script it may take anywhere from 2 minutes to 5 minutes to complete. So while the script executes I need to disable the html button but I want the users to continue using other web pages while the script finishes in the background. Now the real problem is that I want to enable the html button back, when the process finishes! 
I'm stuck at this from many days. Any help or suggestion is really really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use some "realtime" libraries for django. I personally know [django-realtime](https://github.com/anishmenon/django-realtime) (simple one) and [swampdragon](https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon) (less simple, but more functional). With both of this libraries you can create web-socket connection and send messages to clients from server that way. It may be command for enabling html button or javascript alert or whatever you want.

In your case I advice you first option, because you can send message to client directly from any view. And swampdragon needs model to track changes as far I know.

Answer (score 0):

Like valentjedi suggested, you should be using swampdragon for real time with django.

You should take the first tutorial here: http://swampdragon.net/tutorial/part-1-here-be-dragons-and-thats-a-good-thing/

Then read this as it holds knowledge required to accomplish what you want:
http://swampdragon.net/tutorial/building-a-real-time-server-monitor-app-with-swampdragon-and-django/

However there is a difference between your situation and the example given above, in your situation:

- Use [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/) or any other task queue, since the action you  wait for takes long time to finish, you will need to pass it to the background. (You can also make these tasks occur one after another if you don't want to freeze your system with enormous memory usage).
- Move the part of code that runs the script to your celery task, in this case, **Popen should be called in your Celery task and not in your view (router in swampdragon)**.
- You then create a channel with the user's unique identifier, and add relevant swampdragon javascript code in your html file for the button to subscribe to that user's channel (also consider disabling the feature on your view (router) since front-end code can be tempered with.
- The channel's role will be to pull the [celery task state](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.state), you
  then disable or enable the button according to the state of
  the task.

overview:

1. Create celery task for your script.
2. Create a user unique channel that pulls the task state.
3. Disable or enable the button on the front-end according to the state of the taks, consider displaying failure message in case the script fails  so that the user restart again.

Hope this helps!